# Filter based on root document property

Tags: mongodb

This is the documents structure:

```
{ 
    '_id' : ObjectId('56be1b51a0f4c8591f37f62a'),
    'name': 'Bob',
    'sub_users': [{'_id' : ObjectId('56be1b51a0f4c8591f37f62a')}]
}
{ 
    '_id' : ObjectId('56be1b51a0f4c8591f37f62b'),
    'name': 'Alice',
    'sub_users': [{'_id' : ObjectId('56be1b51a0f4c8591f37f62a')}]
}
```

The `sub_users` array is used basically to link accounts, in the example Alice is Bob's manager since she has him as a sub_user. Bob has his own id in the `sub_users` array and this is wrong (no one really is his own boss).

I want to find all the Bobs, it feels like a simple query but I can't find the way to do it, or to even to google it properly, tried this (probably knowing it wouldn't work);

```
db.users.aggregate([                       
    { $group: { _id: '_id' } },
    { $match: { sub_users: { $elemMatch: { _id: '$$ROOT._id' } } } }
])
```

And it didn't worked, so the question is; how to find a document whose nested documents have the same value as the root element (for a certain field)?

Comment: I'm not very familiar with MongoDB, but in plain JS it seems that something like `users.filter(function(item) { return item._id == item.sub_users._id;});` would work.

Comment: @MichaelL. I believe is not that simple, I'll remove the javascript and json tags since they may not be too relevant here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get there I'm using compare expression - please see example below:

```
db.users.aggregate([{
            $unwind : "$sub_users"
        }, //have all ids on same level
        {
            $project : {
                _id : 1,
                name : 1,
                sameId : {
                    $cmp : ["$_id", "$sub_users._id"]
                },
            }
        }, {
            $match : {
                sameId : 0
            }
        }
    ])
```